# Trouble accessing remote server with public key

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

i am posting this question after extensive search in google to create public key and accessing server using `public key`, i am still unable to resolve this issue, as i am getting below error.

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.12.2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.12.2 [192.168.12.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/authorized_keys type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/authorized_keys-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.12.2:22 as 'ansible'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:YTd6SSDMsb3Qhn8EoF/otK+TY6DSAsahYvZxFErZJnQ
debug1: Host '192.168.12.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: .ssh/authorized_keys (0x560667b2de80), explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
This system is for the use of authorised users only.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1003)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1003)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/authorized_keys
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

`server side - 192.168.12.2 - user:ansible`

```
 chmod 700 .ssh/
 chmod 600 .ssh/*
 ssh-keygen
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ansible@192.168.12.10
 /sbin/restorecon -r .ssh/
```

`client side - 192.168.12.10 - user:ansible`

```
chmod 700 .ssh/
chmod 600 .ssh/*
/sbin/restorecon -r .ssh/
/sbin/restorecon -r .ssh
ssh -vv -i .ssh/authorized_keys -o PasswordAuthentication=no ansible@192.168.12.2
```

in sshd_config file, `PubkeyAuthentication yes` is set at both client & server end.

user credentials has been verified for server when generating keys, and multiple attempts made with passphrase and without passphrase.. but no luck.

most of issues found are of `user ownership`..  i have ensured that both sides user's .ssh/ directory & its files are having user ownership, 700 for .ssh/ directory and 600 for .ssh/ files.

`restorecon` tried but no luck.

as suggested, i have verfied audit log at server end, found this.

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1593508901.404:87844): pid=26089 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=pubkey acct="ansible" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.12.10 terminal=ssh res=failed'

type=USER_ERR msg=audit(1593508901.408:87847): pid=26089 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:bad_ident grantors=? acct="?" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=localhost addr=192.168.12.10 terminal=ssh res=failed'

type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1593508901.409:87851): pid=26089 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=login acct="ansible" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.12.10 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

and `journalctl _COMM=sshd` at server shows below.

```
Jun 30 10:21:41 localhost sshd[26089]: Connection closed by 192.168.12.10 port 47944 [preauth]
```

Comment: `journalctl _COMM=sshd` output for this failed login attempt could be helpful. Also, if you have SeLinux enabled please check auditd logs at `/var/log/audit`.

Comment: @Artem, thanks for your response.. please find outputs from server (have updated my question), do you sense anything from the outputs?? please help if you can

Comment: Your client and server blocks of commands are backwards.  You have set up key authentication to `ssh` from `192.168.12.2` to `192.168.12.10`, not the other way around.

Comment: i hope both ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id must be done at server side (192.168.12.2) and by then client side (192.168.12.10) .ssh/authorized_keys file will be updated with server key. then we try ssh to server.. could you please explain where am i doing wrong???

Comment: `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` must be executed on the client side (192.168.12.10) and then the server side (192.168.12.2) `.ssh/authorized_keys` file will be updated with the client key.  Then you can ssh from the client to the server.

Comment: excellent.. Now i understood my mistake.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a confusion

```
ssh -vv -i .ssh/authorized_keys -o PasswordAuthentication=no ansible@192.168.12.2
```

`authorized_keys` is a list of public keys you allow to connect.

this file should be set on server side.

you must connect using your private keys, likely

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa ansible@192.168.12.2
```

---

## step 1 (client)

connect to 192.168.12.10 with user ansible and type:

```
mkdir .ssh ; chmod go-rwx .ssh ; cd .ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Accept default option, do not set password.

Do this only one, do not do it if there is already a pair of key.

if password for ansible is know, copy file id_rsa.pub using

```
scp id_rsa.pub ansible@192.168.12.2:.ssh/id_rsa_ansible.pub
```

The first time you ssh or scp from 192.168.12.10 to 192.168.12.2, you will have a confirmation dialog.

```
ansible@192.168.12.2:hosts.ansible
The authenticity of host '192.168.12.10' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 89:dc:fe:d6:4a:40:28:e5:e9:d0:bd:09:28:01:93:23.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
```

if password in unknow or unset, copy the line from id_rsa.pub using putty buffer

## step 2 (server)

Connect to 192.168.12.2 with user ansible

```
mkdir .ssh ; chmod go-rwx .ssh ; cd .ssh
```

Create authorization files

```
cat id_rsa_ansible.pub >> authorized_keys
```

or copy/paste content of id_rsa.pub file from ansible

authorized_keys must :

- belong either to ansible (or root)

  ```
  chown ansible authorized_keys
  ```
- ansible must be only writer (rw-r--r--)

  ```
  chmod 644 authorized_keys
  ```

## verification

connect to 192.168.12.10 with user ansible

```
ssh ansible@192.168.12.2
```

You should connect without having to type password

---

I already have a web page detailing those steps (in french and english), you can enter usernames and hostnames.
[image: detail of ssh setup]

Comment: HI Archemar.. do you mean trying "ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa ansible@192.168.12.2" at client 192.168.12.10 with -i option is for server side file??  i have tried this option as well but no luck, and got same permission denied error.

Comment: `id_rsa` should be present on your client; as a default key name, you don't need to specify it with the `-i` option, although it will do no harm to do so.

Comment: -i will look for key at client side or server side??

Comment: `-i` will look for a key on the client side.  Your private key should be on the client; your public key concatenated onto the `authorized_keys` file on the server.

Comment: thanks.. could you please provide answer with server side steps & client side steps.. my ultimate goal is to access server(192.168.12.2) from client (192.168.12.10).. really appreciate your patience, please help.

Comment: you really saved my day.. i was struggling with a client-server confusion since 3days

Comment: thanks a lot.. it works perfectly.